# Running scripts in a homemade package

Tags: python, import, directory-structure

I am working on a project and would like to structure it as follows:

```
project/
├── src/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1.py
│   ├── module2.py
│   └── ...
└── scripts/
    ├── script1.py
    ├── script2.py
    └── ...
```

Inside script1, I obviously want to import stuff from src. I tried using relative imports:

```
#scripts/script1.py
from ..src import module1
```

But that results in an ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.

I know the problem can be circumvented by rearranging the folders, but that would result in a less organized project hierarchy.

What is the best approach to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the `project` folder to `sys.path` and use absolute imports.